# how to retrieve the value from a cell of specific row and column python?

Tags: python

```
    2020-04-13
2020-04-14
2020-04-15
2020-04-16
2020-04-17
2020-04-20
2020-04-21
2020-04-22
2020-04-23
2020-04-24
2020-04-27
2020-04-28
2020-04-29
2020-04-30
2020-05-01
2020-05-04
2020-05-05
2020-05-06
2020-05-07
2020-05-08
2020-05-11
2020-05-12
2020-05-13
2020-05-14
2020-05-15
2020-05-18
2020-05-19
2020-05-20
2020-05-21
2020-05-22
```

I want to retrieve value from 2020-04-20(todays date) column of 3rd row from the above.This is the result of

```
print(data.columns)
```

I tried using get_value and .at.It didnt work

print(data.columns)

```
for i in data.columns:
    convert_date=i.date()#converting to date type
    if date.today()==convert_date:#comparing todays date
        print(date.today())
        print(data.at[3,date.today()])#throws KeyError: datetime.date(2020, 4, 20)
```

Comment: Well, for one, your using `date.today()` (a date) to index something which apparently has a datetime index. I'd recommend reading some basic tutorials on time series and pandas dataframes and numpy arrays though, because I think you're making a problem harder than it really is. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve exactly, except that you've made a mistake in doing so.

Comment: after that you can see I have converted to date object inside for loop

Comment: Yes and `date` is not `datetime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your index into `datetime` object. Currently its string. you can change index into datetime :

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

After that it should work.